# how to handle the view without snackbar?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, snackbar

Location rights are essential for my application.
Go to settings in snackbar to obtain location rights.

The problem is that the external widget is touched when snackbar is activated.
I want to prevent it from touching anything except the snack bar.

```
val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.mainLayout,
                        R.string.suggest_permissison_grant,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
                    )
                    snackBar.setAction("check") {
                        val intent = Intent()
                        intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                        val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                        intent.data = uri
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }

                    snackBar.show()
```

i tried to addCallback, addFlag... but those things are banned entire screen(activity)

```
val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                        binding.mainLayout,
                        R.string.suggest_permissison_grant,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
                    ).addCallback(object : BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>(){
                        override fun onShown(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?) {
                            super.onShown(transientBottomBar)
                            setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)

                        }

                        override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?, event: Int) {
                            super.onDismissed(transientBottomBar, event)

                        }
                    })
```